# What is the history of "Modulex" blocks?

Tags: history

I have seen a few very small models using something called "Modulex" pieces and have even heard that they are somehow directly related to LEGO? They don't seem to be around anymore so I was wondering what their history was?

Comment: Not around anymore? I have a 2x5 right here! (At some time, they produced a [planning board](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=Mx15367) which my company still uses for operator shifts.)

Comment: @Joubarc I meant that I didn't believe you could still buy them new. I am sure there are plenty of people who have there sets still.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Modulex bricks were produced by LEGO mainly for architects as the dimensions were more easy to scale up (they are 5mm in all directions).

You can find a full history (which I confess I didn't read) [here](http://minibricksmadness.com/2011/05/18/paper-about-the-history-of-modulex/)

In time, Modulex started to focus more on signage and separated from LEGO, but it [still exists nowadays](http://www.modulex.com/).

Answer (score 4):

The [german Wikipedia article](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulex_M20) states that they were meant to be used by architects, etc. They are much easier to use for to-scale models, because they are 5 mm high (which results in a comfortable 1:20 scale). It would be quite hard to do that with the standard 8x9.6 mm LEGO bricks.